# How to convert one object to array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My object is like this:

```
var response = {
    "HotelNo": "1",
    "HCode": "IDGOR_00008",
    "Name": "Amaris Hotel Gorontalo",
    "CheckIn": "2016-05-01",
    "CheckOut": "2016-05-02",
    "Currency": "IDR",
    "TotalRate": "380000",
    "Status": "OR"
}
```

I want change the object to object array like this:

```
var response = [{
    "HotelNo": "1",
    "HCode": "IDGOR_00004",
    "Name": "Maqna Hotel",
    "CheckIn": "2016-05-01",
    "CheckOut": "2016-05-02",
    "Currency": "IDR",
    "TotalRate": "582960",
    "Status": "OK"
}];
```

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: And what are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do some of the property values change once in the array? At least make your example output consistent with the example input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the object in array

```
response = [response];
```

Comment: I need you help. look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209847/how-to-send-parameter-json-array-when-modal-open